# How to declare a variable as a unit with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

In astronomy the value of the Hubble constant is still somewhat uncertain. Therefore, it is customarily written as `$H = h \SI{100}{\kilo\meter\per\second\per\mega\parsec}$`, where `$h$` is now considered part of the unit. The unit for length is `$h^{-1} \si{\mega\parsec}$`, which I want to typeset as `$\si{\per\h\mega\parsec}$`. How do I achieve this in latex so that 'h' is typeset in italics like a variable? Below is a minimal example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit \h {$h$}
\DeclareSIUnit \parsec {pc}


\begin{document}

\si{\per\h\mega\parsec}

\end{document}
```

This bails with an error:

```
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.11 \si{\per\h\mega\parsec}

?
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: If `h` is a unit, then it should not be typeset in `italics`.

Comment: As @ChristianHupfer said if you use `\DeclareSIUnit \h {h}` you should get the desired results.

Comment: Can you point to a source where the symbol is used as you say?

Comment: From an Astrophysicists point of view this typesetting is wrong and completely unsual (I've not seen it this way)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Hm, I see it all the time, e.g. within the text of Eisenstein etal 2005 [link](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2005ApJ...633..560E) or Figs 4,5 in Alipour etal 2015 [link](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2015PhRvD..91h3520A). Perhaps I should check how they wrote their LaTeX code...

Comment: @hsgg: I see that those authors do it this way, nevertheless, it's not nice in output

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: I don't ssee why you don't like it. Many others do it, too. h is not really a unit, it is a variable, but often you can treat it as a unit, and if I do treat it as a unit, I get to use `siunitx`'s `\SI{}{}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I do not know about the typesetting of units in the astronomy, thus I cannot say, how the "h" should be typeset, but an "h" in math italics is easy:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit \h {\ensuremath{\mathit{h}}}
\DeclareSIUnit \parsec {pc}

\begin{document}
  \si{\per\h\mega\parsec} 
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This and the other answer work nicely. I also had another thought: How about `\DeclareSIUnit \h {\text{$h$}}`. How to choose which one is the best answer?

Answer (score 10):

Escape in text mode and then use math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit \h {\text{$h$}}
\DeclareSIUnit \parsec {pc}

\begin{document}

\unit{\per\h\mega\parsec} \unit[per-mode=fraction]{\per\h\mega\parsec}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you heard of `\ensuremath` ;-)

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, and *consciously* avoided it.

Comment: What is the advange of using `\mbox` over `\ensuremath` or `\text{$ $}`? Looks like you have a good reason.

Comment: @alfC `$h^{-1}$` is not the same as `$\mbox{$h$}^{-1}$`

Comment: I believe something changed in `siunitx`, as this does not work any more: the *h* is not scaled in the denominator with texlive 2023.

Comment: @campa I blame Joseph.  Now it should work.