# Declare a SIUnit in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, siunitx

I want to declare the Bohr magneton \mu_\text{B} as a SI unit in the siunitx package within mathmode. I used the following definition in the preamble:

```
\DeclareSIUnit \muB {$\mu_\text{B}$}
```

Overleaf is giving an error because of this as "Missing { inserted. You need to enclose all mathematical expressions and symbols with special markers. These special markers create a ‘math mode’."

This question is closely related to:
[How to declare a variable as a unit with siunitx?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239863/how-to-declare-a-variable-as-a-unit-with-siunitx)

But all solutions from this question are giving the same result:

```
\DeclareSIUnit \muB {\ensuremath{\mu_\text{B}}}
\DeclareSIUnit \muB {\mbox{$\mu_\text{B}$}}
```

How can one define a SI unit, which needs math mode?

Comment: First of `\text{B}` is not really correct here. This works fine for me: `\DeclareSIUnit\muB{\ensuremath{\mu_{\mathrm{B}}}}`, if it does not for you, provide a full but minimal example so we know exactly what you are doing.

Comment: Refer to [section 9.3](https://texdoc.org/serve/siunitx/0) of the manual. Using `\ensuremath` seems to be the canonical way to do this.

Comment: \DeclareSIUnit\muB{\ensuremath{\mu_{\mathrm{B}}}} works perfectly, thank you very much!